# Upload a CSV FIle in php and make it as json format

Tags: php, mongodb, csv, file-upload, json

I have a csv file and i want to upload this csv file to mongoDB. through a php function.
    Id  Handle
    1  Naveen
    2  Bos
How can i read and make it as json encoded format in php
This is my needed json format

```
{"id" : "1", "handle" : "Naveen"},
{"id" : "2", "handle" : "Bos"}
```

i am using this code

```
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])) {
            echo "<h1>" . "File ". $_FILES['filename']['name'] ." uploaded successfully." . "</h1>";
            echo "<h2>Displaying contents:</h2>";
            readfile($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']);
        }
        $handle = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r");

        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $data=json_encode($data);
            print_r($data);         
        }

        fclose($handle);    
        print "Import done";    

    }
else {
    print "<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='upload.php' method='post'>";
    print "File name to import:<br />\n";
    print "<input size='50' type='file' name='filename'><br />\n";
    print "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Upload'></form>";
}
```

The output is `id,name 1,naveen 2,bos ["id","name"]["1","naveen"]["2","bos"]`
My needed jsonencoded format is this

```
{"id" : "1", "handle" : "Naveen"},
{"id" : "2", "handle" : "Bos"}
```

How can i get this? please help

Comment: Insufficient basic research. The question shows no effort to even look for a basic coding library in the language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$keys="";
    $result=array();
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        if($keys==""){
            $keys = $data;
        }else{
            $output = array();          
            for ($i=0; $i <count($keys) ; $i++) { 
                $output[$keys[$i]]=$data[$i];

            }
            array_push($result, $output);
        }
    }
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r(json_encode($result));
    echo "</pre>";
```